# Check User logged in or not in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

**Problem statement**

1. I have many posts and pages and in every post, there is an anchor tag having a link to the pdf file.
2. I want to restrict the users to view the pdf file if the user is not logged in and redirect them to a login or sign up the page in WordPress.
3. And I also want to show the different content based on different users like - paid users, subscribers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't link directly to the PDF file. Don't even give the PDF file a public URL.

Link to a PHP program which does whatever user authentication/authorization you want and then acts according to that. If the decision made is to serve them the PDF, then use the `header()` function to set the correct content-type for it, and `readfile()` to output the PDF data.

Comment: Can you please share demo code or link so that I can go through? Can I write the PHP code in the WordPress posts or pages?